# Head to Head or adjacent regular expression

Tags: regex

*Hey i want a regular expression where word not repeated head to head and password must be alpha numeric*

Example

pp47klm                on this give a error message

p47kplm                this one is write

Please Help me to make this regular expression where word not repeated head to head or Adjacent

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "word not repeated head to head"? I fail to see a repeated word in your "error" example. Do you mean character? Or should "abcabc" also be considered an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for an alphanumeric password that does not contain any doubled characters, then

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)\w+$
```

would fit these requirements. However, that is not really a good password validating regex (as it will also allow `1` as a password), so you might want to think about your requirements a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: yup this one is quite nearest to my answer but password should be alphanumeric

Comment: @user1577099: `\w+` does match an alphanumeric string of at least one character.